# Ruby on Rails 3: How to use MapReduce with the MongoDB Ruby driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mapreduce

How can I use MapReduce in Ruby on Rails if I'm using the [MongoDB Ruby driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your map and reduce js functions as variables, and then something along these lines:

```
activities = Connection.new(host,port).db(dbname).collection('activities')
activities.mapreduce(map,reduce,:out=>'analytics')
```

The 'analytics' collection will hold the result of the mapreduce operation.